# jquery on change does not work in asp net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Can someone explain me why this code below does not hit the on change function?

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownList("Relatorios", ViewBag.Tipos as SelectList, new { id = "Relatorios"})
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Relatorios").on("change", function () {
        alert("Success");
    });
});
```

I expected that function to hit when I change de option in the drop down list

Comment: It would be better if you included the rendered html

Comment: Also have you checked the console to check for errors

Comment: Could be that jquery isn't installed when your script runs - this would give an error in the console (in browser, press F12 then select *console*).  Open console then open/refresh your page and make  change.  You can add some additional debugging such as a console.log before doc.read and just inside doc.ready to ensure these are working.

Comment: I posted the solution as a answer. Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem with the code below

```
$(window).load(function () {
        $("#Relatorios").on("change", function () {
            settabledata();
        });
```